# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have URL rewrite mode enabled for my localhost (apache) server well. But as soon as I try to get access the remote URL via my localhost. it prompts error as:

```
"Internal Server Error" or sometime "Not Found"
```

and if I make little change (by removing [P]) in my htaccess file then it's showing the expected URL at console log but still it prompts error as -

```
" No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."
```

My .htaccess file is as:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://<Remote_ip_address>:<port_no>%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
 </IfModule>
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an intentional security feature (the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). You need to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) on the destination server (not in your `.htaccess` file here, but on `Remote_ip_address`). Here are a few resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
- http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Thanks Thilo...  So, I need to make changes in Destination server's config file(.htaccess or .httpd) and not in my local one. if yes then in which file .htaccess or in .httpd file on destination server ?

Answer (score 0):

This solution below works for me in the vhost file located there :

/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/xxxx.conf

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(yourdomain\.com|otherdomain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
```

**DO NOT FORGET**

- to change ***yourdomain.com|otherdomain.com***
- To add/modify the correct Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, PUT,PUATCH, DELETE, POST